# Use sed to replace percent signs with brackets

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I need to replace text surrounded by percent signs with brackets, eg:

> This %is% a %test%

should become

> This {is} a {test}

I tried: sed 's/\%([^]]*)\%/{\1}/g'

But that resulted in:

> This {is% a %test}

Comment: Wrong character in the exclusion class: `[^]]*` --> `[^%]*`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ echo "This %is% a %test%" | sed -e 's/%\([^%]*\)%/{\1}/g'
This {is} a {test}
```

- you need to escape the groups: `\(...\)` (otherwise you get `invalid reference \1 on 's' command's RHS`)
- use `[^%]*` to match anything but `%`
- you don't need to escape `%` (but it works with `\%` aswell).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using `awk` instead:

```
s='This %is% a %test%'
awk -F'%' '{for (i=1; i<NF; i++) p = p $i (i%2 ? "{" : "}"); print p $NF}' <<< "$s"
This {is} a {test}
```

Comment: In that case I prefer perl: `echo ... | perl -ne 's/%(.*?)%/{\1}/g; print'` ;-)